# Frama-c: save plugin analysis results in c file

Tags: c, static-analysis, frama-c

I'am new in frama-c. So I apologize  in advance for my question.

I would like to make a plugin that will modify the source code, clone some functions, insert some functions calls and I would like my plugin to generate a second file that will contain the modified version of the input file.

I would like to know if it is possible to generate a new file c with frama-c. For example, the results of the Sparecode and Semantic constant folding plugins are displayed on the terminal directly and not in a file. So I would like to know if Frama-c has the function to write to a file instead of sending the result of the analysis to the standard output.

Of course we can redirect the output of frama-c to a file.c for example, but in this case, for the plugin scf for example, the results of value is there and I found that frama-c replaces for example the "for" loops by while.

But what I would like is that frama-c can generate a file that will contain my original code plus the modifications that I would have inserted.

I looked in the directory src / kernel_services / ast_printing but I have not really found functions that can guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line, option `-ocode <file>` indicates that any subsequent `-print` will be done in `<file>` instead of the standard output (use `-ocode ""` after that if you want to print on stdout again). Note that `-print` prints the code corresponding to the current project. You can use `-then-on <prj>` to change the project you're interested in. More information is of course available in [the user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-user-manual.pdf).

All of this is of course available programmatically. In particular, `File.pretty_ast` by defaults pretty-prints (i.e. output a C program) the AST of the current project on stdout, but takes two optional argument for changing the project or the formatter to which the output should be done.